# boost is installed but powershell says "Did not find"

Tags: powershell, boost, osquery

I have installed boost-msvc14 1.59.0 but whenever I try installing osquery it says that it didn't find boost-msvc14 1.59.0 .

[image]

My boost directory is in C:/local. powershell is very slow in terms of downloading that's why I don't want to use powershell to install it. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Just as a hint, regarding downloads: use this snippet `(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile( '$url, $path)`. This is faster than `Invoke-Webrequest`

Comment: @restless1987it's already written that.

Answer (score 0):

Old question.  In recent osquery builds, you can use the make-win64-dev-env.bat, which uses Chocolatey packages.  They get placed in \ProgramData\chocolatey.  You can run `choco list -l` to list your installed packages.